# Jenkins Deployment Issue - Unrecognized SSL Message, Plaintext Connection?

Tags: jenkins, git, deployment, ssl, tomcat

I've been attempting to **build** and **deploy** a local copy of a repository, whilst still providing the remote depository to Jenkins, to a Tomcat version 9 server.

I have both Jenkins and Tomcat running on different ports.

I did get a handful of successful builds and deployments but I found that when I would visit my successful deployments via the Tomcat server, any page other than the home page of the build had a 404 error.

I thought it was because the dependencies were absent because it was using Jenkins workspace instead of the local repository on my device, so after switching directories, I relieved the following error:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.906 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-07T14:11:59-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying C:\Users\(myusername)\Projects\ier_ui\target\derui.war to container Tomcat 9.x Remote with context derui
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [C:\Users\(myusername)\Projects\ier_ui\target\derui.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:188)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:169)
    ... 18 more
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:169)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

After struggling with this error for a couple days, I decided to completely delete and reinstall Jenkins and started from scratch. The reason I did this is because I wanted to get a successful build and start working from Jenkins Worksapce directory again, instead of my local repo, but even after the reinstall I have been getting the error which I thought was unique to me changing the workspace location.

Any ideas what this might be due to? Perhaps access issues to the apache-tomcat folder? But even then, it was working before. Your insights would be highly appreciated.

Just to be clear, I do provide the correct credentials for Tomcat and my git repository platform. This include `manager-gui` and `manager-script` roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it's because the link for tomcat I was deploying to was: `https://localhost:portNo`, instead of simply, `http://localhost:portNo`